# Taking Screenshot of Current screen

Tags: android, screenshot

I am working on an application on Android which will share the screen to another android device.This app will run in background as service.

I want to capture the screen (current screen),save it as JPEG and continously send it over UDP to other Android device.

But my problem is how to capture the current screen by capturing framebuffer .

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the screenshot of a layout by enabling

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

of the view.

Check this [link](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/10/how-to-create-screenshot-of-application-and-store-it-in-sdcard/)

Comment: Thanks. But this would only give the screenshot of my application view.I want to capture whatever appears on screen when my application runs in background

Comment: you want the screenshot of the background service...that i dont know...hope someone will help you

Answer (score 7):

The Android framebuffer (and on other linux systems) is accessed by opening the /dev/graphics/fb0 device. This requires root access and even with root access it won't work properly on all devices. Most devices use a pair of framebuffers and toggle between them. The bigger problem is that even with a rooted phone, the Dalvik machine's user ID does not have the privilege to access the frame buffer (fb0) device. This means that you will never be able to open and read from the fb0 device directly from Java code. You will need to run a native linux application as root and it will be able to access fb0 (after the user gives permission). I succeeded in making this work and it is quite challenging and also frowned upon by Google. I still may potentially turn this into a commercial application, but the limitations and incompatibilities put the probability quite low.

Comment: I used the link http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1473 to access the frame buffers. But when I use the same code using a service for continous screenshots then I get memory problem. But when I capture a single screen using an activity then there is no memory error. Can u help

Comment: Are you mapping and unmapping the framebuffer memory or are you keeping a pointer to it and using it multiple times? I was able to continuously capture the screen by keeping fb0 open while I was using it.

Comment: I am using pointer to it.Can u share the code. I am using the same procedure as mentioned in the link above mentioned by me  pocketmagic.net/?p=1473

Comment: I would rather not share the code since I still may use it for a commercial application.